# binding a rabbitmq service

Tags: rabbitmq, cloud-foundry, vmc

With vmc I pushed my java application into cloudfoundry and I created a rabbitmq service bound to this application, I have tested two or three applications like that and all works so good, but from few days I had a problem to bind a rabbitmq service to neither an existing application nor a new one and I got this message :

```
user@user-System-I7:~$ vmc bind-service rabbitmq-broker myApp
NoMethodError: undefined method `service_by_name' for #<CFoundry::V1::Client:0x7f417344f4b0>
For more information, see ~/.vmc/crash
```

and when I type :  user@user-System-I7:~$more ~/.vmc/crash  I get

```
Time of crash:
Wed Jan 02 15:06:31 +0100 2013

NoMethodError: undefined method `service_by_name' for #<CFoundry::V1::Client:0x7f417344f4b0>

vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli.rb:406:in `send'
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli.rb:406:in `by_name'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/inputs.rb:150:in `instance_exec'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/inputs.rb:150:in `convert_given'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/inputs.rb:113:in `get'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/inputs.rb:69:in `[]'
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli/service/bind.rb:15:in `bind_service'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/base.rb:61:in `send'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/base.rb:61:in `run'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:68:in `invoke'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:82:in `instance_exec'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:82:in `invoke'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/base.rb:50:in `execute'
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli.rb:106:in `execute'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership.rb:45:in `start'
vmc-0.4.7/bin/vmc:11
1.8/bin/vmc:19:in `load'
1.8/bin/vmc:19
```

Please help !!

Answer (score 1):

I had the [same problem](https://cloudfoundry.atlassian.net/browse/CF-216).  It seems to be a bit of a mystery but I worked around it by downgrading vmc to 0.4.4.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when binding a mongodb service, I solved it by using

```
vmc bind-service
```